# Filter and sort related data from multiple lists

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, visual-studio

I've been working on ways to collect data from a few lists, do some calculations on it and set up user controls to filter/sort that data. Ultimately I want a web part (or similar) that a user can use to sift through data and rearrange it in a meaningful way. The path I've begun to take is coding a web part from scratch that does this, but I was wondering before I sink a lot of time into it if there already exists a way to do this so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: My immediate thoughts go out to using multiple listview webparts that are connected and filter together from the same filter input. This would be achievable with the out ofbthe box webparts in a simplified way.